# Octave - random generate number

Tags: random, numbers, octave

I have a simple question about randomly generating numbers in Octave/Matlab.

How do I randomly generate a (one!) number (that is either 0 or 1)?

I could really use an example.

Thanx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [rand](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/rand.html), which generates a uniform pseudo-random number in the range 0..1, and then test this value against a suitable threshold, e.g. 0.5 for equal probability of 1 or 0:

```
r = rand > 0.5
```

Comment: how do I compare 2 vectors of equal length - I want to get number of elements that differ.
Example:

x=1 0 0 1 1

y=1 0 1 1 0

result should be 2

Comment: You should probably post this as a new question as it's not related to the current question.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `randi` for integer random numbers:

```
randi(2) - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of variety, here's another way

```
floor(rand*2)
```