# Does the rand function ever produce values of 0 or 1 in MATLAB/Octave?

Tags: matlab, random, octave

I'm looking for a function that will generate random values between `0` and `1`, inclusive. I have generated 120,000 random values by using `rand()` function in octave, but haven't once got the values `0` or `1` as output. Does `rand()` ever produce such values? If not, is there any other function I can use to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you read the documentation of `rand` in both [Octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/rand.html) and [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html), it is an **open** interval between `(0,1)`, so no, it shouldn't generate the numbers 0 or 1.

However, you can perhaps generate a set of random **integers**, then normalize the values so that they lie between `[0,1]`.  So perhaps use something like `randi` ([MATLAB docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html), [Octave docs](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/randi.html)) where it generates integer values from 1 up to a given maximum.  With this, define this maximum number, then subtract by 1 and divide by this offset maximum to get values between `[0,1]` inclusive:

```
max_num = 10000; %// Define maximum number
N = 1000; %// Define size of vector
out = (randi(max_num, N, 1) - 1) / (max_num - 1); %// Output
```

If you want this to act more like `rand` but including 0 and 1, make the `max_num` variable quite large.

Comment: Nice trick +1 :) BTW, I didn't see the **open interval** part in the documentation. am i missing something?

Comment: @SanthanSalai - It's on my docs on MATLAB R2013a.  I just checked the MATLAB docs on MathWorks and you're indeed right.

Comment: @rayryeng Even though the doc page seems to have removed the detail about the open interval for some reason, it remains in the help (`help rand` in R2015a).

Comment: @Rayryeng:Thanks a lot. it is really helpful :)

Comment: Sure! If you no longer need help, consider accepting one of our answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

*Mathematically*, if you sample from a *(continuous) uniform distribution on the closed interval [0 1]*, values 0 and 1 (or any value, in fact) have probability *strictly zero*.

*Programmatically*,

1. If you have a random generator that produces values of type `double` on the *closed* interval [0 1], the probability of getting the value 0, or 1, is not zero, but it's *so small it can be neglected*.
2. If the random generator produces values from the *open* interval (0, 1), the probability of getting a value 0, or 1, is *strictly zero*.

So the probability is either strictly zero or so small it can be neglected. Therefore, you shouldn't worry about that: in either case the probability is zero for practical purposes. Even if `rand` were of type (1) above, and thus *could* produce `0` and `1`, it would produce them with probability so small that you would "never" see those values.

Does that sound strange? Well, that happens with any number. You "never" see `rand` ever outputting exactly 1/4, either. There are so many possible outputs, all of them equally likely, that *the probability of any given output is virtually zero*.

Comment: `rand` doesn't sample from the closed interval `[0,1]`, it samples from the open interval `(0,1)`. It should never (not just vanishingly rarely) produce 1.

Comment: It would be nice to explicitly give the probability of hitting a given double-value (~1e-16) instead of *so small it can be neglected*.

Comment: @mbschenkel The probability will be ~1e-16 (as given by `eps`) if `rand` outputs _all_ existing `double` values between `0` and `1` with the _same_ probability. As much as that would be the most desirable behaviour for `rand`, we can't be sure that's really the case, unless it's documented

Comment: @LuisMendo Questioning whether `rand` gives all outputs with the same probability doesn't really make sense, given that it's a pseudo-RNG. Mersenne Twister passes stringent tests of randomness (such as Diehard), and is k-distributed at 32-bit accuracy for all k<623 - in other words, all possible 2^(32k) combinations of bits occur the same number of times within a period. Those sorts of properties are as close as you can get to your requirements for a PRNG.

Comment: @SamRoberts "_all possible 2^(32k) combinations of bits occur the same number of times within a period_" That's what I meant by "_the same probability_". Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: I just wanted to point out that `rand()` certainly does not "output all existing double values between 0 and 1 with the same probability", since that wouldn't be uniform.  Since `double` is a floating-point type, the representable values are not evenly spaced, and therefore the probability of each value should be equal to the distance to its neighbor, resulting in `CDF(x) = x` which is the description of a uniform distribution.  (Another way to produce a uniform distribution would be to give equal chance to each value from an evenly spaced set, and never return other values such as subnormals)

Comment: @LuisMendo ok, I have to ask (now that I got a familiar face to do it to) ... what is with this sudden wave of people doing minor edits on really old octave questions lately?! xD  I've seen at least 5 this week!

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou No idea :-) What happened in my case is: I got an upvote on this answer, which prompted me to re-read it, and I inevitably found some parts that could be improved

Answer (score 5):

`rand` produces numbers from the *open* interval `(0,1)`, which does not include 0 or 1, so you should never get those values.. This was more clearly documented in previous versions, but it's still stated in the help text for `rand` (type `help rand` rather than `doc rand`).

However, since it produces doubles, there are only a finite number of values that it will actually produce. The precise set varies depending on the RNG algorithm used. For Mersenne twister, the default algorithm, the possible values are all multiples of 2^(-53), within the open interval `(0,1)`. (See `doc RandStream.list`, and then "Choosing a Random Number Generator" for info on other generators).

Note that 2^(-53) is eps/2. Therefore, it's equivalent to drawing from the closed interval `[2^(-53), 1-2^(-53)]`, or `[eps/2, 1-eps/2]`.

You can scale this interval to `[0,1]` by subtracting eps/2 and dividing by 1-eps. (Use `format hex` to display enough precision to check that at the bit level).

So `x = (rand-eps/2)/(1-eps)` should give you values on the closed interval `[0,1]`.

But I should give a word of caution: they've put a lot of effort into making sure that output of `rand` gives an appropriate distribution of any given double within `(0,1)`, and I don't think you're going to get the same nice properties on `[0,1]` if you apply the scaling I suggested. My knowledge of floating-point math and RNGs isn't up to explaining why, or what you might do about that.

Comment: Is it documented that the minimum is `eps(1)` and not `eps(0)`? For `eps(0)` your code would generate negative values.

Comment: @Daniel I'm not sure what you mean by "the minimum" - the minimum what? My answer said `eps`, which is by definition `eps(1)`, not `eps(0)` - I haven't suggested using `eps(0)` anywhere.

Comment: When the minimum which `rand` outputs is `eps(0)`, your code would generate negative values. `eps(0)` is the smallest positive double, so it might be returned by `rand`. Don't know.

Comment: @Daniel No, the minimum returned by `rand` (when using the Mersenne Twister algorithm) is 2^(-53) or eps/2, as I mentioned in my answer. That's documented in the doc page I referred to in my answer.

Comment: "*it's still stated in the help text for rand (type help rand)*": It's no more in the help (4.2.2), so the mystery still exists, unless `(0,1)` mentioned in the doc can be read as *exclusive* of 0 and 1, which seems likely.

Comment: @mins Yes, `(0,1)` is the standard notation for an open interval, excluding the endpoints 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this:

```
octave:1> max(rand(10000000,1))
ans =  1.00000

octave:2> min(rand(10000000,1))
ans =    3.3788e-08
```

Did not give me 0 strictly, so watch out for floating point operations.

**Edit**

Even though I said, *watch out for floating point operations* I did fall for that. As @eigenchris pointed out:

```
format long g
octave:1> a=max(rand(1000000,1))
a =    0.999999711020176
```

It yields a floating number **close** to one, not equal, as you can see now after changing the precision, as @rayryeng suggested.

Comment: You may want to check if that is truly `1.0`, or just a rounded version of the floating point number.

Comment: Good catch, not 1 just Octave's display, I'll fix the answer

Comment: @brodroll - Try changing the display format.  Do `format long g;` then try running the code again.  I've run it several times and I never get exactly `1.0`.  Here's one run on my instance of Octave.  BTW +1 for your answer.  `octave:1> format long g;
octave:2> max(rand(100000000,1))
ans =    0.999999988570948
octave:3> format 
octave:4> ans
ans =  1.00000`

Comment: Yup made the changes for further reference and completion. Thanks for the heads up guys!

Answer (score 1):

Although not direct to the question here, I find it helpful to link to this SO post [Octave - random generate number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300803/octave-random-generate-number) that has a one liner to generate 1s and 0s using `r = rand > 0.5`.